# How to change the area occupied by tiled windows from the default 50% of screen area?

Tags: kde, plasma-5, tiling

The Quick Tile Window keyboard shortcut <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow left</kbd> makes the window in focus occupy the left half of the screen. <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow right</kbd> makes the focused window occupy the right half.

By using these two shortcuts, two windows occupy space in a 1:1 ratio.

How can I modify these shortcuts to have the left window occupy 45% and the right window 55%?

Comment: I suspect it will be easier to make your own scripts to do what you want using something like `wmctrl` than to modify the system's defaults. Alternatively, you could visit the KDE Store for scripts such as [KWin Quick Tile Enhancements](https://www.pling.com/p/1309653) or something else that meets your needs. Make sure you pick something that matches your version of KDE Plasma. All the best! (See https://www.pling.com/browse/cat/210/order/latest/) for more kwin scripts.)

Comment: See [How do I resize the active window to 50% with wmctrl?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/53150/61798). I guess you can modify the code to suit your purpose.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find an easy solution in the basic linux settings.

But there is a Project on GitHub: https://github.com/pkkid/pygrid

Comment: Better if you provide some more information regarding this

Answer (score 1):

While its not the setting you described, you may find this extension helpful:
https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/28/gtile/

With this you can tile windows to 12.5% screen columns (like 62.5 - 37.5)